# IS it possible to to put jquery attribs before html ones?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using `$html attrib` for inserting data attrib to my index.html file using jquery. I have also typed attribs manually.

Now is it possible if I press f12 to see the `$html attribs` first before the manual attribs?

E.g

```
html data-id="Code" lang="en-PH"
```

i set lang attrib manually and data id code via jquery.

If I press f12 lang comes first before data id. I want data id first before lang.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's *possible*, by iterating over all attributes that exist on the element and deleting them, then adding your own new attribute, then re-adding the originals...

```js
const div = $('div')[0];

// Cache and remove existing attributes
const attribs = [];
for (const attrib of div.attributes) {
  attribs.push([attrib.name, attrib.value]);
  div.removeAttribute(attrib.name);
}

// Add your own
$(div).attr('dynamicAttrib', 'dynamicVal');

// Re-add original attibutes
for (const [name, value] of attribs) {
  $(div).attr(name, value);
}
console.log(div.outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div firstAttrib="firstValue"></div>
```

But whether a piece of code works or not should not depend on attribute order. It's somewhat convoluted and doesn't accomplish anything, and [could even cause problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73848885/is-it-possible-to-to-put-jquery-attribs-before-html-ones/73848918?noredirect=1#comment130399667_73848918); I'd recommend not bothering.

Comment: Beware that by specs the order of attributes is implementation defined, and that removing and adding attributes will have side-effects, some of which are not small ones (e.g setting the `src` of an `iframe` will cause the reloading of the iframe and possibly the refetching of all its content).